# How do I create a ColdFusion web service client that uses WS-Security?

Tags: web-services, coldfusion, ws-security

I've exposed several web services in our product using Java and WS-Security. One of our customers wants to consume the web service using ColdFusion. Does ColdFusion support WS-Security? Can I get around it by writing a Java client and using that in ColdFusion?

(I don't know much about ColdFusion).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm assuming you mean you need to pass the security in as part of the SOAP header. Here's a sample on how to connect to a .Net service.  Same approach should apply w/ Java, just the url's would be different.

```
<cfset local.soapHeader = xmlNew()>
<cfset local.soapHeader.TheSoapHeader = xmlElemNew(local.soapHeader, "http://someurl.com/", "TheSoapHeader")>
<cfset local.soapHeader.TheSoapHeader.UserName.XmlText = "foo">
<cfset local.soapHeader.TheSoapHeader.UserName.XmlAttributes["xsi:type"] = "xsd:string">

<cfset local.soapHeader.TheSoapHeader = xmlElemNew(local.soapHeader, "http://webserviceUrl.com/", "TheSoapHeader")>
<cfset local.soapHeader.TheSoapHeader.Password.XmlText = "bar">
<cfset local.soapHeader.TheSoapHeader.Password.XmlAttributes["xsi:type"] = "xsd:string">

<cfset theWebService = createObject("webservice","http://webserviceUrl.com/Webservice.asmx?WSDL")>
<cfset addSOAPRequestHeader(theWebService, "ignoredNameSpace", "ignoredName", local.soapHeader, false)>

<cfset aResponse = theWebService.SomeMethod(arg1)>
```

Hope this is what you needed.

Comment: I'll have to try this out. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This is probably more accurate to produce the 'simple' xml soap header. The example above is missing a few lines.

```
Local['soapHeader'] = xmlNew();
Local['soapHeader']['UsernameToken'] =  xmlElemNew(local.soapHeader, "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd", "UsernameToken");
Local['soapHeader']['UsernameToken']['username'] =  xmlElemNew(local.soapHeader, "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd", "username");
Local['soapHeader']['UsernameToken']['username'].XmlText = Arguments.szUserName;
Local['soapHeader']['UsernameToken']['username'].XmlAttributes["xsi:type"] = "xsd:string";
Local['soapHeader']['UsernameToken']['password'] =  xmlElemNew(local.soapHeader, "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd", "password");
Local['soapHeader']['UsernameToken']['password'].XmlText = Arguments.szPassword;
Local['soapHeader']['UsernameToken']['password'].XmlAttributes["xsi:type"] = "xsd:string";
addSOAPRequestHeader(ws, "ignoredNameSpace", "ignoredName", Local.soapHeader, false);
```

Answer (score 1):

I've never done any ws-security, and don't know if ColdFusion can consume it or not, but to answer your secondary question:

> > Can I get around it by writing a java client and using that in coldfusion?

Yes, absolutely. ColdFusion can easily use Java objects and methods.